# C++ why does this parallel for loop with vector.insert() crash when loop size gets larger?

Tags: c++, openmp

I have nested loops that inserts integers into a vector of empty vectors a1i.

```
vector<vector<int>> a1i = {{},{},{},{},{},{},{}...};

#pragma omp parallel for simd
for(int x = 0;x < a1i.size();x++){
   for(int y = 0; y < x - 1; y++){
      a1i[x].insert(a1i[x].end(),y);
   }
}
```

the vector would then looks something like this after the loop.

```
a1i = {
{},
{},
{0},
{0,1},
{0,1,2},
{0,1,2,3},
{0,1,2,3,4}
...
}
```

the loop behaves nicely when the size of a1i is small but if it is big e.g.5000 elements my program crashes because of the loops.

If I estimate the size of the vector of vectors, to be half a 5000 by 5000 vector of vectors of integers it should only take up around 50,000,000 bytes (50 megabytes).I am sure I have more than 50 megabytes memory. 
The vector is a global variable so it should be in heap?

Or is there something else here that takes up massive amounts of memory?

Is my estimation in the right order of magnitude?

Is the problem trying to vector.insert() concurrently?

The way I see it is that each thread will be inserting into a different vector within a1i so I don't suspect anything there.

Am I missing something that is very obvious?

Comment: What is the type of `ali`? Inserting into `std::vector` is indeed not thread safe

Comment: vector<vector<int>> a1i;

Comment: do you have any idea why it only crashes for larger loops?

Comment: Concurrent insertion to vector is not possible without synchronizing thread writes.

Comment: but isn't it different vectors within the vector? and why does it work for smaller loops?

Comment: for small sizes of a1i (<1000 empty vectors), I get the correct output and a speedup compared to a single threaded version. @arnes

Comment: @2wings Being not thread-safe doesn't mean it will immediately crash. It means, if you manipulate the resource from different threads, you are rolling dice whether race condition occurs or not. So the answer is that <1000 empty vectors are just lucky.

Comment: @arnes can I use vector.insert() on thread local vectors without worrying about this? or is .insert() a global resource like cout?

Comment: if i create a new vector called p for each loop iteration would that be fine?

Comment: @2wings The principle is if you are calling non-thread-safe function from multiple threads   in a unsynchronized way it would result in unexcepted results. Otherwise it should work appropriately.

Comment: `a1i[x].insert(a1i[x].end(),y)` is simply `a1i[x].push_back(y)`

Comment: What is the error message it crashes with?

Comment: Your memory may be getting fragmented due to vector reallocations. Remove reallocations with `a1i[x].reserve(x - 1);` before the 2nd loop.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean? I am new to C++, I have only used a bit of python before. I thought .insert(.end(),element) is the same as .emplace_back(element)? And how does .reserve help?

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin with your suggestion i got this error:terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error'
  what():  vector::reserve

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve: _`std::length_error` if `new_cap > max_size()`_. Don't reserve `-1` elements. `a1i[x].reserve(std::max(0, x - 1));`

Comment: aside from allocating memory does using .emplace_back() avoid work as well?

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Am I using vector.insert() in a safe way? Or should i still create thread local vectors?

Comment: @2wings If only the top loop is parallelised, then `vector.push_back` is race-condition free because only one thread ever modifies each vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expected OMP gain of parallel work on all `a1i[x]` which are indeed independent so omp thread safe will be decreased by the cost of increasing `a1i[x]` vector size dynamically (by calling insert or push_back).
A better solution performance wise would be:

```
vector<vector<int>> a1i = {{},{},{},{},{},{},{}...};

#pragma omp parallel for simd
for(int x = 0;x < a1i.size();x++){
  a1i[x].reserve(x); 
   for(int y = 0; y < x - 1; y++){
      a1i[x].push_back(y);
   }
}
```

or

```
#pragma omp parallel for simd
for(int x = 0;x < a1i.size();x++){
  a1i[x].resize(x); 
   for(int y = 0; y < x - 1; y++){
      a1i[x]= y;
   }
}
```